# The set of one-parameter subgroup of the Multiplicative group $G_m$ is Z

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G_m= k^{*}=k-{0}$ be the multiplicative group. We know this is an Algebraic group also. How does one prove any algebraic group morphism  $G_m \rightarrow G_m$ is of the form $t \mapsto t^{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Note that an algebraic group morphism is a morphism of varieties which is also a group homomorphism.

Comment: Do you really want to call the group $G_m$?. Wouldn't $G$ be better?

Comment: This are notations being used for a long time. One can refer to "Linear algebraic Groups" by James Humphreys.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval $G_m$ is very standard notation in this situation.

Comment: Right, I see. I got confused with the other $m$, the one in $t\mapsto t^m$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: Oh, I see. Yeah that is confusing. May be I should edit it to $t \mapsto t^{n}$

Comment: Is there any assumption on $k$, or should this be true for any field?

Comment: When you say algebraic group morphism, this essentially means a polynomial map which is multiplicative. Right ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus : Yeah, true. As both the algebraic groups are affine the morphism is given by polynomials in each co-ordinate. And it has to be multiplicative because it is an group homomorphism.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval It is true for $k$ algebraically closed. I am not sure whether the statement is true for any general field.

Comment: OK, but there is only one coordinate, and it could be rational, maybe if $k$ is not algebraically closed.

Comment: To think $G_m$ as an affine variety , you need to consider it inside $k^2$. The zeros of $yx=0$ and $y=0$ in $k[x.y]$

Comment: So isnt $G_m=k[t,t^{-1}]$ under multiplication ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: That will be its affine co-ordinate ring. There is an one-to-one correspondence between $k-{0}$ and zeros of $xy=1$, the second viewed inside $k^2$. In that sense $k-{0}$ can be thought of an affine variety. And the co-ordinate ring of that will be $k[x,y]/(xy-1)=(k[x])[x^{-1}]=k[x,x^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi:G_m\to G_m$ be defined by $t\mapsto\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$, where $f,g$ are polynomials. Assume $k$ is algebraically closed. If one of $f,g$ is not $t^n$ for some $n$,then it maps a nonzero element in $k$ to $0$. Thus for $\varphi$ to be well defined, the nonzero roots of $f$ and $g$ must be the same, meaning that $\varphi(t)=t^l$ for some $l$.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that $k$ is infinite. If $f(x)$ is a polynomial such that 
$f(st)=f(s)f(t)$ all $s,t \in k^*$, then $f(tx)=f(t)f(x)$ holds for all nonzero $x$, but if $k$ is infinite this implies it holds for all $x$. Therefore $f(0)=f(t)f(0)$ so either $f$ is constant (=1) or $f(0)=0$, and $f$ has no constant term. Now one can assume that $f(x)=x^mg(x)$ and repeat the same argument for $g$. This also works for rational functions where if we assume that the numerator and denominator have nonzero constant coefficients a contradiction results.